# Self not Working while calling from function

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

```
def lbl():
    lbl1=Label(self,text='hello',fg='red').place(x=10,y=10) 

class login(Frame):
        global self
        def __init__(self,parent,controller):
                Frame.__init__(self,parent)
                btn=Button(self,text='view',command=lbl).place(x=40,y=40)
```

now in the above function it is giving error that name self is not defined

Comment: Why did you put `global self` in your class? and also please post a [mre]

Comment: `self` should never be made global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `lbl` to be able to access `self`, it should be a method on your class.

```
class login(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,controller):
        ...
        btn=Button(self,text='view',command=self.lbl).place(x=40,y=40)
        #                                   ^^^^^
    def lbl(self):
        lbl1=Label(self,text='hello',fg='red').place(x=10,y=10)
```

If there's a reason that you don't want it to be a method on your class, then you need to rename the variable `self` inside that function, and have the function accept a parameter that identifies the parent of the label:

```
def lbl(parent):
    #   ^^^^^^
    lbl1=Label(parent,text='hello',fg='red').place(x=10,y=10) 
    #          ^^^^^^


class login(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,controller):
        ...
        btn=Button(self,text='view',command=lambda: lbl(self)).place(x=40,y=40)
        #                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```